# Quickbooks: Authentication and authorization without human interaction

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Can anyone provide a way to get the access token & refresh token without human interaction?
I've one account with which I have to make all the requests to quickbooks and don't want all my application users to provide quickbooks credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably misunderstanding how OAuth works, specifically in the context of how Intuit wants it's customers to securely grant you access to QuickBooks data.

For each company who wants to connect your app to QuickBooks, you'll need human interaction to occur *just once*, and *only once*. This is not optional. It is mandatory. Human interaction is required one single time, and then after that you can exchange data with QuickBooks whenever you want, without any further interaction with a human.

Your application users will never provide QuickBooks credentials to you directly (e.g. you should *not* be collecting QuickBooks passwords or usernames).

Build your app to support OAuth2:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0

For each QuickBooks company (not each user, but each *company*) that you want to exchange data with, have one user auth via OAuth, just once.

You'll receive an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. Save those in your database.

Once you save those, you never have to have a human interaction again for that connected company.

Use those tokens to make calls to QuickBooks. When the access token expires, use the refresh token to get a new access and refresh token. Save both new tokens to your database. Use those to make calls in the future. Repeat.